# How to fetch the records from custom table and display in admin panel?

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a custom_table which stores the download details of a pdf documents. For which we need to have link in the wordpress admin panel so that by clicking on that link the admin users can view the data that is available in the custom_table.

Any idea of how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way it's to use the `$wpdb` class, which handles the connection to the database.

On the initialization of your plugin, globalize `$wpdb` and set your table name as:

`$wpdb->my_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table_name'`

Then, you can use `$wpdb->get_results()`, `$wpdb->get_row()`, `$wpdb->get_col()` or `$wpdb->get_var()` depending on what you need to get from the database.

For instance:

`$downloads = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->my_table WHERE author_id = %d", $author_id) );`

Check the docs on http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thanks for help. How can i enable a link in the admin panel so that to facilitate the admin users to view the data just by clickin it.

Comment: You'll want to add an admin menu, and inside that maybe a table with the data. Checkout the docs on http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus